# UPDATE una base de datos con Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando hacer un update a una base de datos con php, quiero que pueda cambiar el username, email, password y avatar desde un formulario ubicado en **settings.php**, hice el código pero el presionar en el botón submit me recarga la pagina con el error 'Data not Updated.'

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include ("includes/database.php");
include ("includes/values.php");
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Update']))
    {

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $records = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET 'username'=:username, 'email'=:email, 'password'=:password WHERE 'id' = :id");
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $message = '';

        $pdoExec = $records->execute(array(":username"=>$username,":email"=>$email,":password"=>$password,":id"=>$id));

        if($pdoExec)
        {
            echo 'Data Updated.';
        }else {
            echo 'Data not Updated.';
        }

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>General Account Settings</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php require 'partials/header.php' ?>
        <h2 style="top:50px;left:150px;position:absolute;">General Account Settings</h2>
        <h2 style="top:300px;left:150px;position:absolute;">Detailed information</h2>

    <form id="settings" style="top:120px;left:560px;position:absolute;" action="settings.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <img style="top:0px;left:-410px;position:absolute;border-radius:5px;" src="<?php echo $user['avatar'] ?>" height="100" width="100"/>
    <input style="top:110px;left:-410px;position:absolute;" type="file" nam="avatar">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo $user['username'] ?>">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email'] ?>">
      <input type="password" name="password">
      <input style="width:150px;top:450px;left:550px;position:absolute;" type="submit" name="Update" value="Save Changes">
    </form>

    <span style="top:135px;left:480px;position:absolute;">Username:</span>
    <span style="top:170px;left:480px;position:absolute;">Email:</span>
    <span style="top:205px;left:480px;position:absolute;">Password:</span>
    <span style="top:360px;left:150px;position:absolute;">Joined <?php echo $user['signupdatefull']?></span>
    
</body>
</html>
```

En **includes/values.php** es donde estoy seleccionando todo de mi base de datos, les dejo el código también.

```html
<?php 
session_start();
    
include ("includes/database.php");

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
        $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user = null;
        if (count($results) > 0) {
          $user = $results;
        }
      }
?>
```

No se si debería dejar la base de datos pero de todas formas tengo una única tabla llamada "**users**", en su estructura están los datos que quiero que se puedan actualizar "**username, email, password, avatar**", username y email tienen etiquetas únicas, no se si influya en algo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO... No entiendo qué quieres decir con esto: *pero solo me actualiza sin ningún cambio, ...*  No es posible una actualización sin ningún cambio  ¿¡..!.? ¿Qué es lo que se imprime por pantalla? ¿Prueba a sacar la consulta: `echo $sql;` y pruébala directamente en `phpmyadmin`, puede que se esté creando erróneamente o que no cumpla los criterios, o que viole restricciones de integridad referencial u otras restricciones.

Comment: Al darle al botón me vuelve a settings.php es decir, se recarga la pagina pero no se actualizan los cambios ni allí ni en la base de datos.

Comment: Escribe la consulta aparte, para que la puedas probar: `$consulta="UPDATE users SET username = '$username', email = '$email', password = '$password', avatar = '$namea' WHERE id = '$id'";`, luego haz un `echo $consulta;` y revísala/pruébala en `phpmyadmin`. Además, en la 1ª parte del código usas `mysqli`, mientras que en `values.php` es código `PDO`... ¿finalmente qué estás usando para manejar las base de datos, `mysqli` o `PDO`?

Comment: Para manejar la base de datos creo que PDO.

Comment: Debes cambiar entonces todo el código de la 1ª parte por código PDO. En todo él usas funciones de `mysqli`, son dos cosas diferentes. Fíjate todas las funciones que usas: `mysqli_query, mysqli_fetch_array, mysqli_num_rows` .... debes aclararte en eso y decidirte por una API. Yo te recomendaría PDO. En el Manual de PHP explican (en castellano) cómo se usa cada función. Tienes que modificar casi todo el código de la 1ª parte.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, paro ahora me sale un error.

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho, actualizado a PDO o pasado todo a mysqli? Muestra cómo queda el código ahora. Y muestra también el error. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/228177/edit) para agregar el código actual y el error actual.

Comment: Lo actualice a PDO, ya edite la pregunta con el código actual y el error.

Comment: Bueno tienes varios errores, intentaré corregirlos en una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código, los enumero brevemente según los veo aparecer y finalmente propongo una corrección:

1. Tienes dos `execute` y el primero está vacío, sin parámetros.
2. Evita poner comillas simples en los nombres de columna de la instrucción SQL. Si quieres usa este tipo de comillas `
3. He usado un operador ternario para capturar los valores del POST, haciendo una evaluación con `empty`. Eso evitará llenar el log de errores con mensajes como *Undefined index*  y permitirá hacer evaluación sobre columnas esenciales de la tabla. O sea, si en la tabla hay alguna columna que no puede ser `NULL` o vacía, deberás poner un `if` para verificar el estado de las variables respectivas a esa columna.
4. No sirve de nada usar `fetch` en consultas que no traen conjunto de resultados como `UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT`. Más bien deberías verificar cuántas filas fueron afectadas por esa consulta.

Este es el código que propongo. Incluye un posible mensaje de error. Pruébalo y dime el resultado en comentarios.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/database.php");
include ("includes/values.php");

    if ( isset($_POST['Update']) )
    {
        $id       = ( empty($_POST['id']) )       ? NULL : $_POST['id'];
        $username = ( empty($_POST['username']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['username'];
        $email    = ( empty($_POST['email']) )    ? NULL : $_POST['email'];
        $password = ( empty($_POST['password']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['password'];
        /*Aquí se puede hacer alguna comprobación si alguna de las columnas son obligatorias o no admiten NULL*/ 
        $sql="UPDATE `users` SET `username`=:username, `email`=:email, `password`=:password WHERE `id` = :id";
        $records = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $params=array(":username"=>$username,":email"=>$email,":password"=>$password,":id"=>$id);

        if ( $records->execute($params) ) 
        {
            $totalRows=$records->rowCount();
            $msg= ( $totalRows > 0 ) ? "Se actualizaron $totalRows filas" :  "Data not updated";
        } else {
            $msg="Ocurrió un error: ".$conn->errorInfo()[2];
        }
        echo $msg;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo "Data not updated"

Comment: @Steoz puede ser porque no se cumple el criterio del `WHERE`, en ese caso no actualizará nada.